# What services are safe to disable?

Tags: boot, performance

I'm configuring my own server, running Ubuntu 13.04. I'd like to speed up the OS a bit more by removing ‘unnecessary’ system services. Here is what I did:

Install and start `rcconf` to check what services are enabled on boot:

```
$ sudo apt-get install rcconf
$ sudo rcconf
```

Uncheck some services like `brltty`, `speed-dispatcher`, `saned`, `rsync`.

I'm still not sure about some services like apparmor, grub-common, kerneloops, ondemand and pppd-dns. Is it safe to disable them? Do I need to uninstall those services or is disabling them is enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the ones you listed, I can tell you that you most likely don't want to disable:

- ondemand
- apparmor and
- grub-common

ondemand is your cpu governor, and without it your CPU will run at full speed all of the time, even when it doesn't have to.

[apparmor](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor) is an access control system that protects your system, see the link for more info.

[grub-common](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2) is the boot loader, and I'm not exactly sure why it is starting on boot, but you probably don't want to disable it.

You might disable [kerneloops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel_oops), it is something of a bug reporting software from what I can gather. Although if you run into a kernel bug, I am pretty sure you will want it enabled.

Honestly removing service in order to "speed up" your system won't do you that much good, unless there's something you **know** you don't need for a server, like bluetooth. Googling services can help with telling you want they do though.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I did some search on them but since I'm far from an expert, I wanted to make sure I'm on the right track.

Comment: What to you suggest to "speed up" servers, besides diabling services and removing unused applications and temporary packeges stored in HDD?

Comment: Yes, kerneloops is a bug reporting software. However, it's really lightweight. grub-common cleans up grub state. Don't disable it.

Answer (score 2):

I do not have the privileges to comment, so I post.

In the past the `kerneloops` daemon was innocuous because multi-user could precede (aesthetically anyways) to the login screen.  However due to the migration to SystemD this daemon triggers the `network-online.service`.

I don't know about you... but I have never seen a commercial DHCP service with low latency response times.  So unfortunately for the kernel developers; `systemctl disable kerneloops`.